# replacing only single instances of a character with python regexp

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace single `$` characters with something else, and want to ignore multiple `$` characters in a row, and I can't quite figure out how. I tried using lookahead:

```
s='$a $$b $$$c $d'
re.sub('\$(?!\$)','z',s)
```

This gives me:

```
'za $zb $$zc zd'
```

when what I want is

```
'za $$b $$$c zd'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

notes, if not using a callable for the replacement function:

- you would need look-ahead because you must not match if followed by `$`
- you would need look-behind because you must not match if preceded by `$`

not as elegant but this is very readable:

```
>>> def dollar_repl(matchobj):
...     val = matchobj.group(0)
...     if val == '$':
...         val = 'z'
...     return val
... 
>>> import re
>>> s = '$a $$b $$$c $d'
>>> re.sub('\$+', dollar_repl, s)
'za $$b $$$c zd'
```

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. It looks like I can get it to work if I used both lookahead and lookbehind. Seems like there should be an easier way, though.

```
>>> re.sub('(?<!\$)\$(?!\$)','z',s)
'za $$b $$$c zd'
```

Comment: still the shortest way to accomplish the task +1.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, without lookaround and without callback function:

```
re.sub('(^|[^$])\$([^$]|$)', '\1z\2', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative with `re.split`:

```
''.join('z' if x == '$' else x for x in re.split('(\$+)', s))
```