# Replace single instance of character in a string, leave multiple characters untouched

Tags: c#, regex

How would I replace `periods` with `spaces`, but preserve `...`?

```
string test = "This.is.a.test...";

test = test.Replace(".", " ");
```

http://rextester.com/DLEHI1253

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644300/replacing-only-single-instances-of-a-character-with-python-regexp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this `(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)`

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)");
var ressult = regex.Replace("This.is.a.test..."," ");
Console.WriteLine(ressult);
```

Output

```
This is a test...
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wv34tV)